# Ionic 3 error property doest not exist on type Object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

when i am running app its showing me error of Property `'records'` does not exist on type `'Object'`.
i try to add records: Observable; 
but its not working can any one tell me how ill solve this . Thanks

attach `.ts` and `.html` file .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HospitalPage } from '../hospital/hospital';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

data: Observable<any>;
records: Observable<any>;
 galleryType = 'regular';
 list: any;

  token: string;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public httpClient:         
 HttpClient) {

    this.token = "token here ";


  }

  getDataUsingToken(token) { 
         return this.httpClient.get('Url',{headers:new HttpHeaders({
                  'token': token
                 }
               )
             }
          ) 
      }

ngOnInit() { 
    this.getDataUsingToken(this.token).subscribe(data=>{ 
      console.log(data); 
      this.list = data.records;

    },

    err => console.log(err.message)
    );
  } 
}
```

**html file:**

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let d of list">
   <div style="font-size: 16px;">{{d.name}}</div>
   <ion-icon name="pin" color="primary"></ion-icon> <font style="font-size: 
      14px;">{{d.city}}</font>
   <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-forward" md="md-arrow-forward" item-right 
  color="primary" class="pin"></ion-icon>

</ion-item>
```

Comment: can you share the template code (html) ? 

Comment: edit question with attached .html .

Comment: Can you try to parse it to JSON  and share the object ?

Comment: i add <any> in hhtpclient.get like this  this.httpClient.get<any> and this works dont know why but after this not showing error .

Comment: please try ionViewWillEnter instead of ngOnInit

Comment: @UmaizKhan check my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try It:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HospitalPage } from '../hospital/hospital';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

data: Observable<any>;
records: Observable<any>;
 galleryType = 'regular';
 list: any;

  token: string;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public httpClient:         
 HttpClient) {

    this.token = "token here ";
    this.gettingData(this.token);


  }

  getDataUsingToken(token) { 
         return this.httpClient.get('Url',{headers:new HttpHeaders({
                  'token': token
                 }
               )
             }
          ) 
      }

gettingData(token) { 
    this.getDataUsingToken(token).subscribe(data=>{ 
      console.log(data); 
      this.list = data.records;

    },

    err => console.log(err.message)
    );
  } 
}
```